# Using TypeScript with body-parser to read req.body properties

Tags: typescript, body-parser

I'm building a web app using TypeScript with the body-parser middleware to parse JSON request bodies. I'm running into type errors when I try to access properties on the `Request.body` object.

For example, if I try, `req.body.username`, TypeScript throws an error

```js
Property 'username' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>'.
```

Things I tried:

- Declaring a custom interface for `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`, just            before accessing the `username` property.

```js
interface ReadableStream<Uint8Array> {
    username: string
}
```

TypeScript informs me that `ReadableStream` was declared but never used. Cannot figure out why this is the case.

- Wrapping usage in an `if` block

```js
if (req.body.hasOwnProperty('username')) {
    // Use req.body.username here
}
```

TypeScript does not seem to understand that this implies that the property username exists.

- Using indexing instead of dot notation

```js
let p_username = req.body['username'];
```

This was the last thing I tried, even though it defeats the point of typechecking. Even this does not work:

```js
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'ReadableStream<Uint8Array>' has no index signature.
```

It seems like reading the request body contents like this is fairly standard usage, and so there should be a simple way to get past this problem. Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to your setup here. As I understand it, the express typings make has the type for `req.body` marked as `any`, so there should be no type restrictions.

Comment: @KevinRaoofi: Are you sure about that? I have strict type-checking enabled. Although explicitly declaring `body:any` in an `interface` does seem to work.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm getting from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e4a0d4f532b177fc800e8ade7f1b39e9879d4b3c/types/express-serve-static-core/index.d.ts#L429). I think I'll need more context as to what you're doing to be able to give you the feedback on what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import the definitions of Request and Response from express library.

On top of file:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem too, I worked around it by creating a new interface and extending the ReadableStream type of the req.body, something like this:

```js
interface User extends ReadableStream<Uint8Array> {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
```

then just adding it to the req.body

```js
  const { username, password } = req.body as User;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Response Body and casting to an object
Generates error:

```
<SampleType>res.body
```

and resolved by this:

```
<SampleType>(<unknown>res.body)
```

I was searching for a resolution but finally looked at the quick fix offered by VSCode of casting to unknown first and then to the type that you want.